# The table I created won't execute with the rest of the code

Tags: java

```
public class BodyMassIndex extends JFrame {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    String user_name;
    String user_height;
    String user_weight;
    Double user_BMI;
    String User_Catagory;
    
JTable jt;
    
    String[] column_headers = {"Name","Height (m)","Weight (Kg)", "BMI", "Catagory"};
    String[][] user_statistics = {{user_name, user_height, user_weight , String.valueOf(user_BMI) , User_Catagory}};
    
    public BodyMassIndex() {
        System.out.print("Enter Your Full Name: ");
        user_name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Your Weight in Pounds: ");
        user_weight = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Your Height in Inches: ");
        user_height = in.nextLine();
        
        
        Double Height_M = (Integer.parseInt(user_height) * 0.0254);
        Double Weight_KG = (Integer.parseInt(user_weight) * 0.453);
        user_BMI = (Integer.parseInt(user_height)/(Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(user_weight) , 2)));
        
        if (user_BMI < 18.5) {
            User_Catagory = "Underweight";
            
        }
        
        else if (user_BMI <= 24.9 && user_BMI >= 18.5) {
            User_Catagory = "Normal or Healthy Weight";
            
        }
        
        else if (user_BMI <= 29.9 && user_BMI >= 25.0) {
            User_Catagory = "Overweight";
            
        }
        
        else {
            User_Catagory = "Obese";
            
        }
        
        jt = new JTable(user_statistics, column_headers);
        jt.setBounds(50,50,200,230);
        JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(jt);
        this.add(js);
        this.setSize(300,400);
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new BodyMassIndex();
        
    }
}
```

I imported everything needed and typed the code above, but when it runs, the program only asks the three questions then it just stops. A table is supposed to display. It's not. How do I make it work? Am I not allowed to use JTable with Scanner? I need to get information from the user then display it in a table.

Answer (score 2):

I have copy pasted your code.
It displayed an empty table for me.
The reason for this is your **user_statistics** field.

You assigned values to it using your other fields (user_name, user_height etc.).

Note that the mentioned fields do not have any value at the time thus your user_statistics is empty when you use it in the JTable constructor.
You should assign these values to it after you got the data from the user.

Simply put you can copy this line just before you are calling JTable constrcutor:

```
String[][] user_statistics = {{user_name, user_height, user_weight , String.valueOf(user_BMI) , User_Catagory}};
jt = new JTable(user_statistics, column_headers);
```

After I did this it displayed the data fine for me.

[image]